# How to make a lagoon?

Tags: ocean-simulation

Does anyone have an idea how to make ocean like this?
[image: lagoon]

I tried to add a plane under ocean modifier but it doesn't seem to work at all, because of volumetric water shader it is super noisy and it looks like crap.(and i think this shader is necessary here to make it look realistic)
I am also confused with the depth value in ocean mod., changing it also doesn't seem to do anything.

PS:I reckon a foam like this would be impossible to make (?)

Comment: you have a foam option in the Ocean modifier

Comment: I know but it looks totally different than foam on the picture